# How to access POST data from a form submitted previously

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that the user will submit multiple values to PHP via POST.

The PHP takes the input and if the data entered is valid, it will display a *second* form for the user to fill out.

After the user has filled out the second form, I need to process the data that was entered in the first form again as well as the data entered in the second form.

What is the best way to access the form data from the first PHP form?

Should I put each value into its own SESSION variable and access it when I need it again later?

I just wasn't sure if this is the best/cleanest way to accomplish this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Your choice is session or a whole bunch of hidden fields on the second form. But as Jeff states, if its on the second form in any way you'll be needing to revalidate that data from the first form upon second form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of sticking it in the `$_SESSION`, but depending on your validation needs, it might be better for you to simply use client-side (javascript) validation and some conditional logic to reveal additional form fields. Then you only have one efficient post to the server with all necessary information.

I think it should go without saying, but nevertheless, once it does post to the server you want to re-validate and sanitize the data.